# Play audio by local file and url in react native

Tags: audio, mobile, react-native

I have found many options, but some only play local files, others support both but do not have a notification when the audio finishes playing.

I would like to be recommended some that could at least play files via url and have a notification of when it ends

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found `react-native-audio-streaming`.

Implementation:

```
import { ReactNativeAudioStreaming } from 'react-native-audio-streaming';

 //Functions

 playSoundTurn() {
    let url = yourURL;
    ReactNativeAudioStreaming.play(url, { showIniOSMediaCenter: false, showInAndroidNotifications: false });

    this.subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
        'AudioBridgeEvent', (evt) => {

            if (evt.status === "STOPPED") {
                // Here finish logic
            }
        }
    );
}

stopSound() {
    ReactNativeAudioStreaming.stop();
}
```

Comment: did `url` mean the path for the file?